# Cannot touch files with var name in bash script for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, touch, var

I'm editing a script for PiHole to convert adblock list format to dns format, to be usable by PiHole.
The idea is to scroll over a lists.list file which contains links to different lists, do a curl to each links of this file and create a file for each links named $link.list which contains all dns names.

***The problem is : ***
I've the message   "touch: cannot touch 'https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylistgermany.txt.list': No such file or directory"

I tried to see if it was some rights issue, so I took the thing to my home/user folder.
If I do

```sh
curl --silent $source >> ads.txt
```

or

```sh
touch ads.txt
```

it works

Here is what I wrote :

```sh
for sources in `cat lists.list`; do
    echo $source
    touch "$source".list
    echo `curl --silent $source` > $source.list
    echo -e "\t`wc -l $source.list | cut -d " " -f 1` lines downloaded"
done
```

And I get

```sh
https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt
touch: cannot touch 'https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt.list': No such file or directory
```

So any suggestions ? 
Thanks for your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the full URL as a file name, but you can't have slashes in file names. Can you name the files to just the last bit in the URL? Then this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for source in `cat lists.list`; do
    echo $source
    filename=$(sed -E 's@.+/@@' <<< $source).list  # <-- remove everything up to and including the last slash
    curl --silent "$source" -o "$filename"
    echo -e "\t`wc -l $filename | cut -d " " -f 1` lines downloaded"
done
```

Comment: Great! If you're happy with it you can mark the answer as "accepted", then I get some sweet, sweet reputation points

Comment: One comment: Why do you use ``cat lists.list``?

Comment: I just copied that from the original. It's one of many ways of iterating over the contents of the file.

Comment: @saintamh: Yeah, but that seems like a UUOC case. Better iterate with a while loop or similiar. I edited your post. Thanks for the great answer.